# Read c++ istream until EOF while discarding the content

Tags: c++, std

I have a `std::istream` where I need to read until `eof`. I'm not interested in the content of the data, but I must ensure all bytes are read from the underlying buffer.

What is the fastest way to read the content of istream until `eof`?

Something like the following code?

```
std::istream str(buffer);
...
std::NULLORWHAT << str.rdbuf();
```

Comment: Why must you ensure all bytes were read?  You could just seek to the end without reading.

Comment: The underlaying streambuf doesn't support seek.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::istream::ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) to read and discard all characters in the stream.

`ignore()` has a default delimiter of `EOF`, so you just need to pass it a number of characters to read.  If you use `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` then `ignore()` does not actually check to see if it reaches that many characters, and will just read until it hits the delimiter.

That gives you

```
str.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
```

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` is not just sufficient, it is required. Passing in any other value will be treated as an actual count, and reading ends when the count is reached before EOF. The count is disabled when passed `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` specifically.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I hadn't noticed it did that.  Thanks for the info.  I've updated the answer.